# Unable to invoke Simple Rest Client using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest

I'm building a project using Spring MVC3.1,in my project I'm implementing the use of restful resources.for this purpose I have downloaded the "Simple Rest Client" extension of Google Chrome Web Browser.But whenever I'm trying to send data from client side I'm getting the error "404 Not Found".below is my controller class named "BookRestController.java"

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/services")
  public class BookRestController {

  private InBookService inBookService;

  public InBookService getInBookService() {
     return inBookService;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setInBookService(InBookService inBookService) {
      this.inBookService = inBookService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers ="Accept=application/xml,application/json")
 public @ResponseBody String addUserBook(@RequestBody UserBook userBook) {
    inBookService.saveBook(userBook);
    return "true";
 }
}
```

Here is my web.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list>
 <session-config>
   <session-timeout>
       30
   </session-timeout>
 </session-config>
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>bsm</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>bsm</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/bsm-servlet.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
   </param-value>
 </context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>com.edifixio.bsm.resource.Label</param-value>
</context-param>
 </web-app>
```

and my servlet spring servlet configuration are as follows named:bsm-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.edifixio.bsm"/>

 <bean class="com.edifixio.bsm.validator.BookValidator"/>
 <bean class="com.edifixio.bsm.validator.SystemUserValidator"/> 

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
   p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
   p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"
   p:suffix=".jsp"/>

   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/data_resources/jdbc_info.properties" />

   <bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
     p:driverClassName="${JDBC_DRIVERCLASS_NAME}"
     p:url="${JDBC_URL}" p:username="${JDBC_USER_NAME}"
     p:password="${JDBC_PASSWORD}"/>

     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
        <value>/WEB-INF/data_resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

      <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${JDBC_DIALECT}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>


   <bean id="transactionManager"
       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean id="transactionInterceptor" abstract="true"       class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
   <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
     <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

and I'm invoking the following url from Simple Rest Client:

```
  http://localhost:8087/BookShopMaintanance-war/services/book
```

can anyone give me any suitable solution to this??????

Comment: I am using JBoss7 not tomcat

Comment: Find out what your application's context root is. Is it `BookShopMaintanance-war`?